# clear both with float doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in Chrome with this example

This is a responsive bootstrap design..

When the `width` is less than `1000px` the green block should press the blue bar down, but in Chrome the blue bar keeps the same position and the green block is layered under it..

http://www.bluemachines.dk/_bootstrap/break/

Comment: Remove the `height: 385px;` to `#presentation`

Comment: @mary, this is not possible due to the design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified height for the '#presentation' div: 385px. The green box in inside this box.

The '#statistics' div is clearing the '#presentation' div so it will sit after the 385px.

SOLUTION:

Either increase the height of the '#presentation' div to include the height of green box.

Or

Remove the height from the '#presentation' div.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving statistics to a new row div!

Answer (score 0):

because fix width is give for classes under .col-md-12

```
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 380px;
    width: 570px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#register {
    float: right;
    height: 380px;
    width: 20%;
    background: green
}
```

use can use bootstrap classes for giving width